# Problem with RAID5 (mdadm) - disk detached

Tags: debian, mdadm, raid5

Having these lines in   /var/log/syslog

```
 Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816036] ata4: EH in SWNCQ mode,QC:qc_active 0x1 sactive 0x1
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816058] ata4: SWNCQ:qc_active 0x1 defer_bits 0x0 last_issue_tag 0x0
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816059]   dhfis 0x1 dmafis 0x1 sdbfis 0x0
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816093] ata4: ATA_REG 0x40 ERR_REG 0x0
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816108] ata4: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sacitve
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816125] ata4: tag 0x0: 1 1 0 1
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816150] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816178] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816199] ata4.00: cmd 61/08:00:00:88:e0/00:00:e8:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 out
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816200]          res 40/00:00:01:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816253] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816272] ata4: hard resetting link
    Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816274] ata4: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
    Apr 18 16:53:06 Server kernel: [4487879.676029] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
    Apr 18 16:53:07 Server kernel: [4487880.416749] ata4.00: n_sectors mismatch 3907029168 != 268435455
    Apr 18 16:53:07 Server kernel: [4487880.416752] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-19)
    Apr 18 16:53:07 Server kernel: [4487880.416773] ata4.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO2
    Apr 18 16:53:11 Server kernel: [4487884.676024] ata4: hard resetting link
    Apr 18 16:53:11 Server kernel: [4487884.676027] ata4: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
    Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.144032] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
    Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.240185] ata4.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
    Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.240190] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
    Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.240210] ata4.00: disabled
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487890.144023] ata4: hard resetting link
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.024033] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.033357] ata4.00: ATA-8: WDC WD20EARS-00S8B1, 80.00A80, max UDMA/133
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.033360] ata4.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048347] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048361] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048365] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048369] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048371]         72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048378]         00 00 00 00
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048382] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048385] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 e8 e0 88 00 00 00 08 00
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048393] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048420] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048440] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048458] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3907028992
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048477] md: super_written gets error=-5, uptodate=0
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048482] raid5: Disk failure on sdc, disabling device.
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048483] raid5: Operation continuing on 3 devices.
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048525] ata4: EH complete
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048554] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048576] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048596] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048615] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY(16) failed
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048617] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048620] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048624] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048643] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048663] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048681] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048683] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048685] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048689] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048709] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048800] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048860] sd 3:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.049028] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.049048] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.049071] sdc: detected capacity change from 2000398934016 to 0
    Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.049080] ata4.00: detaching (SCSI 3:0:0:0)
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.061149] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.485492] RAID5 conf printout:
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.485496]  --- rd:4 wd:3
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.485500]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.485502]  disk 1, o:0, dev:sdc
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.485504]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.485506]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.497014] RAID5 conf printout:
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.497016]  --- rd:4 wd:3
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.497018]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.497019]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.497021]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.838719] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD20EARS-00S 80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.838886] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.838911] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.838964] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.838967] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
    Apr 18 16:53:18 Server kernel: [4487891.838988] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
    Apr 18 16:53:20 Server kernel: [4487891.839147]  sdf: unknown partition table
    Apr 18 16:53:20 Server kernel: [4487893.130026] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
```

Right now, i'm unable to do anything on /dev/sdc. Is there any way to try to re-attach it? I don't want to power-down the server unless absolutely necessary

System:

- Debian Stable 2.6.32-5-amd64
- mdadm version 3.1.4-1+8efb9d1

**cat /proc/mdstat**

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdb[0] sdc[4](F) sde[3] sdd[2]
      5860543488 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [U_UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

**mdadm --examine --scan**

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=1a7744b5:912ec7af:f82a9565:e3b453b4
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --examine --scan` to your question.

Comment: i've updated the post to include requested info

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with the /proc filesystem:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/mlproc.html

Comment: cat: /proc/scsi/scsi: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you think you're going to gain by adding a failing disk back into your array. These errors aren't soft errors - the disk is on it's way out.

```
Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816178] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816199] ata4.00: cmd 61/08:00:00:88:e0/00:00:e8:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 out
Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816200]          res 40/00:00:01:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816253] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816272] ata4: hard resetting link
Apr 18 16:53:05 Server kernel: [4487878.816274] ata4: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
Apr 18 16:53:06 Server kernel: [4487879.676029] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Apr 18 16:53:07 Server kernel: [4487880.416749] ata4.00: n_sectors mismatch 3907029168 != 268435455
Apr 18 16:53:07 Server kernel: [4487880.416752] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-19)
```

Failed a write command, reset the link, now it's seeing a sector mismatch on the drive.

```
Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.240185] ata4.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.240190] ata4.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
Apr 18 16:53:12 Server kernel: [4487885.240210] ata4.00: disabled
```

Failed to respond to an IDENTIFY command.

```
Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048615] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY(16) failed
Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048617] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Apr 18 16:53:17 Server kernel: [4487891.048620] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
```

Drive failed to respond to a READ CAPACITY command.

The fact that the disk returns as far as presenting a block device to linux is a red herring. You should replace it, not spend time trying to get a disk that looks very much like it's failing back into a RAID array. Even if you did get it back in, it'll either fail again shortly, silently corrupt your data, or both.

Replacing SATA disks doesn't technically require powering off the disks. I appreciate that your chassis may not have hotswap bays, and may not allow you easy access to replace the disks, but you might consider taking this opportunity to install a SATA hotswap bay adapter. Something like [this](http://www.addonics.com/products/raid_system/ae4rcs35nsa.asp) from Addonics, for example - fits into 3 5.25" bays, and provides 5x 3.5" hot-swap access drive trays. Makes replacing disks a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Marvell controller. 
I disabled NCQ and this did not happen again.

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/YOUR_DEVICE/device/queue_depth
```

Comment: That's going to kill performance. Not sure this is a "valid" answer...

Comment: yes I know that's suboptimal, anyway the performance degradation depends on the workload. We're talking about an array of green drives, so this is probably a nas which does essentially sequential reads and writes. In this scenario disabling ncq won't hit (much).